# IndexError: pop index out of range problem

Tags: list

pop index out of range problem

```
my_list = [99,7,11,3,26]
my_list.pop(7)
```

error Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    my_list.pop(7)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pop()` method removes the element at the specified position.
There is no item in 7 position. So you are getting an error `IndexError: pop index out of range` [try this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_pop.asp) . Remove the last item of a list just

```
my_list.pop()
```